# Removing instance after several condition

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

How do i solve the *Parameter child must be non-null* error?
I'm trying to remove instances (box1, box2, box3, box4) that have `.y <= 56`

The code follows:

```
for (i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    this["Box" + i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Move);
}

function Move(e:Event):void
{
    e.target.y -=  6;
    if (e.target.y <= 56)
    {
        removeChild(getChildByName(e.target.name));
        Comment.text = "MISS";
        miss +=  1;
        score +=  0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like listener continue to fire after the box is removed, so before this line:

```
removeChild(getChildByName(e.target.name));
```

add this line:

```
MovieClip(e.target).removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Move);
```

Comment: problem solved on this, but same problem happen on my mouse event click with similar code like this : if ((event.target.hitTestObject(bts1))&&(event.target.hitTestObject(bts2))&&(event.target.hitTestObject(bts3))&&(event.target.hitTestObject(bts4)))
 {
  removeChild(getChildByName(event.target.name));
  Comment.text = "PERFECT";
  perfect +=  1;
  score +=  10000;
 }

Comment: So try the same: `MovieClip(e.target).removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, yourClickMouseListener);`

Comment: May be it will be better if you will start a new question with a full code attached?

Answer (score 1):

AS is case-sensitive (like 99% of languages).

Are your instances' names actually capitalized (`Box`) or all-lowercase (`box`) ?

Comment: my bad on typing hahaha its Box

Answer (score 1):

If box are MovieClip (or extend MovieClip):

```
var currentBox:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
currentBox.y -=  6;    
if (currentBox.y <= 56) {
    currentBox.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Move);
    removeChild(currentBox);
    Comment.text = "MISS";
    miss +=  1;
    score +=  0;
}
```

Comment: In your answers you give not only answer , but do some little refactoring too :)